# How to convert the following JS code to VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a JS code and I am trying to convert it to Vue. Basically, I am trying to use this code: https://codepen.io/kimdontdoit/pen/wvdKLJo

And how I am trying to implement this code into mine is:

```
<template>
    <section id="successful-order" class="container">
        <div class="row office-banner">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img :src="successful" alt="Popper Image"/>
                <div class="sub-title">Your order is complete!</div>
                <div>You will be receiving a confirmation email with your order details.</div>
                <div class="button-area">
                    <button class="btn button">Checkout your tickets</button>
                    <button class="btn button-secondary">Go to homepage!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import successful from "../../../../img/poppers.png";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            successful: successful,
            color: ["#8b5642", "#6a696b"],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        frame() {

            
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Basically, I also need to create frame() function but I am quite new in Vue so I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Just... Copy-paste the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a Vue app with the canvas-confetti example you listed with the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-confetti-vue2-psh9k?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

You just need to instal canvas-confetti using npm.
Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <h1 class="office-banner">IT IS YOUR BIRTHDAY.</h1>
</template>

<script>
import confetti from "canvas-confetti";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      colors: ["#8b5642", "#6a696b"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    frame() {
      confetti({
        particleCount: 2,
        angle: 60,
        spread: 55,
        origin: { x: 0 },
        colors: this.colors,
      });
      confetti({
        particleCount: 2,
        angle: 120,
        spread: 55,
        origin: { x: 1 },
        colors: this.colors,
      });

      if (Date.now() < Date.now() + 15000) {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.frame);
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.frame();
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.office-banner {
  background-color: #e2ddd8;
  font-family: "Arial";
  padding: 0.125em;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: -5%;
  right: -5%;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Here's a good article with the title "Use Any JavaScript Library With Vue.js
" that you'd probably be interested in:

- https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

Comment: But how can I add the function into the html? Bceuase I did exactly what you've done but still there is no confetti

Comment: Which function are you referring to? If it is `confetti`, you need to install it using `npm install canvas-confetti` and then import it at the beginning of the  `<script>` tag with `import confetti from "canvas-confetti"`.

Comment: The code is meant as a single file `.vue` component. It needs to be processed with a configured module bundler that you get when you set up a project with the Vue CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the content of `frame()` from Codepen and in the `mounted` life cycle, call this `frame()` method

```js
mounted: function () {
  this.frame()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want your `<script>` block to look somewhat like this :

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            successful: successful,
            color: ["#8b5642", "#6a696b"],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        frame() {
            confetti({
                particleCount: 2,
                angle: 60,
                spread: 55,
                origin: { x: 0 },
                colors: this.data.color,
            });
            confetti({
                particleCount: 2,
                angle: 120,
                spread: 55,
                origin: { x: 1 },
                colors: this.data.color,
            });

            if (Date.now() < Date.now() + 15000) {
                requestAnimationFrame(frame);
            }            
        } 
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.frame();
    }
};
```

The idea is you first declare the function `frame()`, then in the `mounted` hook you call that function. You can read more about the Vue instance and its lifecycle hooks [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)